# What is MAC referring to in a cipher suite?

Tags: x509certificate, tls1.2

For the following cipher suite:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

does MAC (message authentication code algorithm) `SHA384` refers to a hashing function that was used to create certificate's signature:

```
 Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

or the function to create hash of all handshake massages which is sent into "finished" message or maybe something completely different?

Comment: What do you mean by "certificate's signature"? Is this signature inside certificate, or generated on the fly signature for TLS handshake?

Comment: @Zergatul the one inside of a certificate printed by running a command `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout | grep 'Signature Algorithm'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only purpose of signature inside certificate is verification procedure. It doesn't affect TLS handshake process.

In ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:

- SHA384 in used for Finished message hash
- GCM-mode already has built-in MAC. It doesn't need any hash function. So, SHA384 is not used for MAC